# How to get my datasource only once for combobox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, web-services, telerik

I use `telerik:RadComboBox`

Like this  :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1"  EnableLoadOnDemand="true"
                                            ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" CollapseDelay="0" Culture="ar-EG" ExpandDelay="0" Filter="StartsWith" ItemsPerRequest="100"
                                            MarkFirstMatch="true" Skin="Outlook" ValidationGroup="L" Width="202px" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True"
                                            EmptyMessage="-Enter user name-"
                                            EnableItemCaching="true" >
                                            <WebServiceSettings Path="../WebService/Employees.asmx" Method="LoadData" />
```

---

and my web service :

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Employees : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]  
            public RadComboBoxData LoadData(RadComboBoxContext context)
                {

                RadComboBoxData result = new RadComboBoxData();
                DataTable dt = FollowsDAL.GetAllEmployees();

                var allEmployees = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()

                                   orderby r.Field<string>("name")

                                   select new RadComboBoxItemData
                                   {
                                       Text = r.Field<string>("name").ToString().TrimEnd()
                                   };
                string text = context.Text;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    allEmployees = allEmployees.Where(item => item.Text.StartsWith(text));
                }
                //Perform the paging
                // - first skip the amount of items already populated
                // - take the next 10 items
                int numberOfItems = context.NumberOfItems;
                var employees = allEmployees.Skip(numberOfItems).Take(100);


                result.Items = employees.ToArray();


                int endOffset = numberOfItems + employees.Count();
                int totalCount = allEmployees.Count();

                //Check if all items are populated (this is the last page)
                if (endOffset == totalCount)
                    result.EndOfItems = true;

                //Initialize the status message
                result.Message = String.Format("Items <b>1</b>-<b>{0}</b> out of <b>{1}</b>",
                                               endOffset, totalCount);

                return result;
            }}
```

---

My problem is :

Although this control is so fast , every time i enter specific name firstly it fetches the `20000` employee in the datatable `dt` !!!

with every character .

My question is:

- How it 's fast like this  with this bad behavior?
- Is there some way to get all the employees only once ?
- How to enhance the performance?

Comment: How many total records do you expect to have in your table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding, sending request to the Database over and over again for the same purpose is not good for the Application health.

There are basically two ways to make the process fast.

> 1. Bring the Data in the form of DataTable from you DataBase.
> 2. Bring the Data in the form of DataSet from you DataBase.

### DataTable Approach

Fetch all the records from the `Database` during your Form Load. Preserve it in the `ViewState` and not in `Session`. Please take care of this point. Access the Data like below..
Now access the `ViewState`. `Type Cast` it and access the below mentioned function.

```
public static class GetFilteredData
{
    public static DataTable FilterDataTable(this DataTable Dt, string FilterExpression)
    {
        using (DataView Dv = new DataView(Dt))
        {
            Dv.RowFilter = FilterExpression;
            return Dv.ToTable();
        }
    }
}


DataTableObject.FilterDataTable("Search Expression or your string variable")
```

This will return you the `DataTable`. Reassign the data to the control without any DataBase trips. Execute this step whenever you have to filter the records.

### DataSet Approach

This process will send `26 DataTable` from your database. I know it is looking very heavy. But as you have already mentioned that total records will be 25,000. So, all these records will be divided among these tables. Please see below the explanation.

The `ComboBox DataField Text column` can have 26 different `Start With` characters. You have to divide these records according to the `Start with` character. Record start with A will be inserted into First Table. Records start with B will be inserted into second table, records start with C will be inserted into third table and so on till Record start with Z will be inserted into 26th Table.

Please Note that Your `UDT` query will originally be used to insert all records in a `Local Temporary Table`. This `Local Temporary Table` will further have 26 select statements based upon the Start With Character.

Below is the Sample Stored Proc.

```
Create Proc ProcName
As

Create Table #Temp
(
    ColumnName Varchar(50)
)

Insert into #Temp(ColumnName)
Select ColumnName from YourTableName

Select ColumnName From #Temp Where ColumnName like 'a%'
Select ColumnName From #Temp Where ColumnName like 'b%'
Select ColumnName From #Temp Where ColumnName like 'c%'
--UpTo Z
```

Now, Finally you have `26 Tables` and Data will be returned as `DataSet` from your BLL.
Preserve it in `ViewState` only. Now will filtering the data, Please use the below mentioned function.

```
public static class GetFilteredData
{
    public static DataTable FilterDataTable(this DataSet Dt, string FilterExpression)
    {
        string Lowercase = FilterExpression.ToLower();
        Int16 TableID = 0;
        if (Lowercase.StartsWith("a"))
        {
            TableID = 0;
        }
        else if (Lowercase.StartsWith("b"))
        {
            TableID = 1;
        }
        else if (Lowercase.StartsWith("c"))
        {
            TableID = 2;
        }
        //upTo Z
        using (DataView Dv = new DataView(Dt.Tables[TableID]))
        {
            Dv.RowFilter = FilterExpression;
            return Dv.ToTable();
        }
    }
}
```

So what we have understood the significance of using `DataSet Technique` is that, the records are further divided into Sub Nodes in the for of Tables. Your `Search expression` will be implemented on `Splitted Nodes` of `DataSet` rather then the `Original DataSet`.

---

### Code Modification as Per mentioned in the Original Query

Add the following in your Web Application/WebSite only.

```
public static class GetFilteredData
{
    public static DataTable FilterDataTable(this DataTable Dt, string FilterExpression)
    {
        using (DataView Dv = new DataView(Dt))
        {
            Dv.RowFilter = FilterExpression;
            return Dv.ToTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following Property in the `WebForm` itself. The following `Property` will return you the result set from Database in case the `ViewState` is null. Otherwise it will return the `ViewState` preserved data only.

```
public DataTable Employees
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["Employees"] == null)
        {
            return FollowsDAL.GetAllEmployees();
        }
        return (DataTable)ViewState["Employees"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Employees"] = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can access this `ViewState` in your `WebForm` , where you have `Combobox` control. As per my understanding you should go for `DataSet` Approach.

Please note that `WebService` is not required in this context.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i wanna to ask :
-the calling of method to `Fetch all the records from the Database`
in the `page load` or `!page.ispostback`.

-In't using viewstate to store 25000-30000 not recommended?

- which method is more performance ,using the server side or using the webservice?
I will be grateful if u edit my code with your recommended changes.

Comment: **the calling of method to Fetch all the records from the Database in the page load or !page.ispostback.**  !page.ispostback **In't using viewstate to store 25000-30000 not recommended?**. Page will be little heavy. I agreed. **But** Execution/Response Time will be reduced rather then going to Database over and over again on each key press

Comment: can I send another answer with my view incorporated using your code?

Comment: I hope you have used `Ajax Extender control`. The background functionality of this control is to accept all the data first time and on key press it Filters the data Locally. It never goes to database again on each key press.

Comment: One more point that Web Service is not required in this scenario. You are considering it because you want to go to database on each key press.

Answer (score 4):

It is always better to use server side filtering, because you do not need to retreive 20000 records to the webserver to use 10 or 20 items to return.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: server side is slower than web service because i bind the combo box in `page_load` , to avoid unassigned datasource error.

Comment: Could u give me a simple example to use server side without binding in page load

Comment: I mean serverside paging instead of getting all data. In the webservice itself, you can get the n number of rows only from the DB that you want to show.

Comment: I will be grateful if u clarify the idea with a simple example .

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/server-side-paging-using-sql-server-2005 Now in your get all employees function, you can write a paged version. You pass context.NumberOfItems and 100 so that you will fetch  only 100 rows from the db

Comment: sorry my database is `informix` could i do the same with LINQ

Comment: No LinQ can filter after getting all the data only. You can use `SELECT SKIP n LIMIT m` with `informix`

Answer (score 2):

Your DAL should have a method to filter the results based on the sent text, then you add them to the combobox. My DAL is Telerik OpenAccess ORM (Linq2SQL) but you could also write a stored procedure to filter the results as well.

Here is an example of one of my asmx services that populates a radcombobox:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public RadComboBoxData FindEmployee(RadComboBoxContext context)
    {
        RadComboBoxData comboData = new RadComboBoxData();

        using (DataBaseContext dbc = new DataBaseContext())
        {
            IQueryable<Employee> Employees = dbc.FindEmployee(context.Text);

            int itemOffset = context.NumberOfItems;
            int endOffset = Math.Min(itemOffset + 10, Employees.Count());
            List<RadComboBoxItemData> result = new List<RadComboBoxItemData>();

            var AddingEmployees = Employees.Skip(itemOffset).Take(endOffset - itemOffset);
            foreach (var Employee in AddingEmployees)
            {
                RadComboBoxItemData itemData = new RadComboBoxItemData();
                itemData.Text = Employee.Person.FullName;
                itemData.Value = Employee.EmployeeID.ToString();

                result.Add(itemData);
            }


            comboData.EndOfItems = endOffset == Employees.Count();
            comboData.Items = result.ToArray();
            if (Employees.Count() <= 0)
                comboData.Message = "No matches";
            else
                comboData.Message = String.Format("Items <b>1</b>-<b>{0}</b> out of <b>{1}</b>", endOffset, Employees.Count());
            return comboData;
        }
    }
```

and in case you are wondering what my FindEmployee method is:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> FindEmployee(string SearchString, bool IncludeInactive = false)
    {
        return from e in this.Employees
               where
                    (e.EmployeeID.ToString() == SearchString ||
                     e.Person.FirstName.Contains(SearchString) ||
                     e.Person.MiddleName.Contains(SearchString) ||
                     e.Person.LastName.Contains(SearchString) ||
                     (e.Person.FirstName + " " + e.Person.LastName).Contains(SearchString) ||
                     (e.Person.FirstName + " " + e.Person.MiddleName).Contains(SearchString) ||
                     (e.Person.FirstName + " " + e.Person.MiddleName + " " + e.Person.LastName).Contains(SearchString)) &&
                    ((e.Inactive == false || e.Inactive == null) && IncludeInactive == false)
               select e;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method that loaded the values from your database and then stored them in cache. Subsequent calls to this method should return the cached version. Then set the DataSource to this method. That should give you a very nice performance boost.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

Comment: Could u give me a simple example .

Comment: @just_name : Remember to put a Cache expiry too. Otherwise the data wont expire even when the Database has a new version of data.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution should be a mix of answers by @PraVn and @nurgent. Write a stored procedure which filters records by `search` string. Have your DAL call this SP using a method which in-turn is called from your existing web method `public RadComboBoxData LoadData(RadComboBoxContext context)`